# How to deactivate the "network disconnected" popup?

Tags: network-manager, indicator

We have network problems at our company and the network is often disconnected. At each disconnection Ubuntu (12.04) displays a pop-up in the right corner of the screen to inform me of this event. This is really annoying when it comes very often. How do I deactivate this?

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In 12.04, you should be able to toggle that behaviour via the gconf database entry for `nm-applet`, using the `gconftool`  (or `gconftool-2`) command

```
gconftool --set /apps/nm-applet/disable-disconnected-notifications --type bool true
```

You will likely want to disable the corresponding *connected* notification as well

```
gconftool --set /apps/nm-applet/disable-connected-notifications --type bool true
```

You can check the current settings using

```
gconftool -a /apps/nm-applet
```

---

For those seeking an answer for later versions of Ubuntu, @Jos has confirmed that in 14.04 the settings have  been migrated to the main `dconf` database at `/org/gnome/nm-applet` and can be toggled using the GUI `dconf-editor` tool. Modification via the CLI should be possible using [`gsettings`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/gsettings.1.html).

Comment: As I will not see the popup again, I will trust your answer. Thanks. See you.

Answer (score 8):

You can change it with **`gsettings`**:-

> gsettings offers a simple commandline interface to GSettings. It lets you get, set or monitor an individual key for changes.

- To **get** current setting, run following command:

  ```
  gsettings get org.gnome.nm-applet disable-disconnected-notifications
  ```
- To **set** (Enable) of disabling disconnected-notifications, run
  following command:

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.nm-applet disable-disconnected-notifications true
  ```

---

However you can **grep all settings for all available notifications** by `gsettings` as follows:

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep "notifications"
```

& specifically for schema = org.gnome.nm-applet,

```
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.nm-applet
```